# How to setup limeJS in a totally offline workspace

Tags: html, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library, limejs

I'm trying to setup limeJS, the issue is the Internet connection is a problem. I had closure library, box2d, closure compiler and closure templates downloaded separately as .rar files, but I can't find a guide anywhere to set it up like this, everyone just uses(and with reason!!!) the python bin/lime.py init command to get it working. I managed to figure out(yay!) how to setup box2d and closure library but what about the other two?
My laptop is running 64 bits Windows 7. Any help appreciated

All I need is an advice on directory structure, like where to drop the compiler.jar and soy templates .js files, so that when I run the update/create command it doesn't try to download the compiler or templates like it does right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, after taking a quick look at the lime.py file it told me everything I needed, for example both the SoyJs templates file and the compiler need to be in the /path/to/lime/bin/external folder and for example, the lime.py file was expecting a compiler file named compiler-dateOfLatestCompiler.jar instead of compiler.jar.

Answer (score 0):

In general, If you have LimeJS built up in one machine using Python and all, you can just copy paste the whole package anywhere you want and use it just as ususal.
You don't need network once you have all the files/codes for Lime is downloaded.
Infact, you dont even need python for normal development tasks(Python is required to build your js file once you complete development though)

Comment: that is correct, the issue is you have to picture a critical internet situation when approaching this question, at least when it comes to downloading and google access...:(